# Efficiently create list of strings only containing base substrings of another list in Python

Tags: python, performance, list, substring

I have a list that looks like:

```
Cat
Cat eats
Cat eats food
Dog ears
Dog ears listen
Rabbit
```

But I want to create a new list that only takes the base strings, so in this case:

```
Cat
Dog ears
Rabbit
```

I'm thinking I could do a nested for-loop:

```
for each item in the list
    for each "other" item in the list
        if the item is a sub-string of "other"
            remove "other" from the list)
```

... but it's a pretty big dataset, so I was wondering if anybody has ideas for something more efficient than this **O(n^2)** attack.

EDIT: This is not a question about coding syntax/having bugs -- I know how to code what I suggested above. It's a question about if there's a logical way to do this without having to use nested for-loops since that's inefficient.

Comment: what did you try already?

Comment: There's your logic; where is the code you want us to fix?  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.
StackOverflow is not a coding or tutorial service.

Comment: You have the logic already outlined; start writing!  If your data are already sorted, as in your example, then you don't have to check the entire data base, merely the immediately following items, until you find a new base string.  If the data are *not* sorted, then sort them first.

Comment: Hi all, it's not so much the issue of not knowing how to write the code/dealing with a code bug as it is an issue of if there's more efficient logic out there -- the code would work fine with the nested for-loops, but I'm trying to avoid using them for efficiency reasons.

Comment: @tobias_k: what about it?  `Cat` is found first, and serves as base string for everything following that begins with `Cat`.  We simply ignore anything until `startswith(base)` comes up `False`.

Comment: @Prune Misunderstood you then. I though you wanted to compare pairs of consecutive strings, but if instead you compare the current string to the last "base string", it should work.

Comment: That's the idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can group the data and find the minimum listing from each group:

```
import itertools
s = """
Cat
Cat eats
Cat eats food
Dog ears
Dog ears listen
Rabbit
"""
listings = list(map(str.split, filter(None, s.split('\n'))))
new_s = [' '.join(min((list(b)), key=len)) for a, b in itertools.groupby(listings, key=lambda x:x[0])]
```

Output:

```
['Cat', 'Dog ears', 'Rabbit']
```

Comment: Could you split this filtered mapped sorted grouped list comprehension across multiple lines for readability, or better, a bunch of aptly named temporary variables?

Comment: How about `listings = [x for x in s.splitlines() if x]`?

Comment: Did not test it, but I think this will fail for `listings = ["dog ears", "dog eyes"]`, i.e. two lines that have the same first word but do not have a common base (the first word on its own not being in the list).

Answer (score 0):

First, sort the list.  Now, maintain a variable that knows the most recent base phrase.  ignore anything that matches.  When you find something different, put it in your list of base phrases and change that variable.

```
base = sorted_list[0]
new_list = [base]

for phrase in sorted_list:
    if not phrase.startswith(base):
        new_list.append(phrase)
        base = phrase
```

Comment: Good point ... editing ... I can do this by simply starting with the first element; the first loop iteration fails safe.